# Concatenate every other row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

**I have an Excel sheet that looks like this:**

```
3  | latitude | 46.142737

3  | longitude| -57.608968

8  | latitude | 43.142737

8  | longitude| -52.608968

15 | latitude | 41.142737

15 | longitude| -59.608968
```

**I need the end result to look like this:**

```
3  | 46.142737, -57.608968

8  | 43.142737, -52.608968

15 | 41.142737, -59.608968
```

It can be concatenated based on every other row, or based on the integer value in the first column.

VBA suggestions? Thank you.

Edit: There is no actual "|" in my Excel sheet. The "|" is meant to be a visual cue representing a new column.

Comment: You can use filter and filter "latitude" out. Or you would like to write a re-usable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the data into an array and then write that to a range

Original Data:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim arry As Variant

    ReDim arry(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As Variant

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 1).Row Mod 2 = 1 Then
            x = x + 1

            ReDim Preserve arry(1 To 2, 1 To x) As Variant
            arry(1, x) = Cells(i, 1).Value
            arry(2, x) = Cells(i, 3).Value & ", " & Cells(i + 1, 3).Value
        End If
    Next

    arry = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arry)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(arry), UBound(arry, 2))).Value = arry
End Sub
```